# success function in ajax doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have an ajax function and I want on `success` to change CSS for some HTML elements, in the `success` I did :

```
success:function(d){
        $('#name').css('weight','normal');
        $('#msg').css('weight','normal');
        $('#date').css('weight','normal');
}
```

But It won't work.

When I do this :

```
success:function(d){
        alert('some thing');
}
```

It worked.

so I think the problem is from the code I used in the `success` function.

Comment: I think you must use `font-weight` instead of `weight`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `weight` CSS property, try with `font-weight`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
success:function(d){
    $('#name').css('font-weight','normal');
    $('#msg').css('font-weight','normal');
    $('#date').css('font-weight','normal');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

font-weight is the correct property name....
    Also you can mention all selectors in single line since operation is same..

Use this code...

```
$('#name, #msg, #date').css('font-weight','normal');
```